# Java StringTokenizer running out of bounds with .CSV file

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, stringtokenizer

I am trying to read a simple .CSV file and create a 2D array of Strings. Here is the array:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4
```

My code is supposed to find six columns and four rows, but it stops after the third column and moves on to the next row and I cannot figure out why this is happening.

In addition to this, it returns an out of bounds exception even though it quits early.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
```

Here is the code and it is followed by the output.

```
public String[][] ascToStringArray(String ascFileIn) {

    String directory ="c:\\data\\"; // "\" is an illegal character

    String[][] numbers= new String[4][6]; // 4 rows 6 columns
    try{
        BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory + ascFileIn));
        String line;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        //read each line of text file
        while((line = Br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            //Populating Columns
            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                //get next token and store it in the array
                numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                System.out.println(row + " " + col + " = " + st.nextToken());
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
        //close the file
        Br.close();

        return numbers;
    }
    catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file.");
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0 0 = 1
0 1 = 1
0 2 = 1
1 3 = 2
1 4 = 2
1 5 = 2
```

If anyone can figure out why it is quitting early and throwing me an out of bounds error no matter how large I make the array I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to reinitialize the `col` variable inside the while loop that reads the lines from the .CSV file. Currently, it will get to the end of a single line and then cause your IndexOutOfboundsException

Comment: Use a CSV library like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `nextToken` twice.

```
numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();<-1---
System.out.println(row + " " + col + " = " + st.nextToken());<--2--Skips element
```

But using only one value so in one row only three element of line will be added.

### Reason of Exception

You are not resetting the `col=0` after the execution of *inner while loop* which leads to `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` for `col=6` as *col size* in array is *6* means 0 to 5 so will throw exception when `col=6`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the system.out.println inside the inner while loop consumes a token.. Second on entring the inner while loop you should reset the `cols` files. to zero.

```
public String[][] ascToStringArray(String ascFileIn) {

    String directory = "c:\\data\\"; // "\" is an illegal character

    String[][] numbers = new String[4][6]; // 4 rows 6 columns
    try {
        BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory + ascFileIn));
        String line;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        // read each line of text file
        while ((line = Br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            col = 0;
            // Populating Columns
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                // get next token and store it in the array
                numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
        // close the file
        Br.close();

        return numbers;
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file.");
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calling st.nextToken() twice, swallowing an extra token in your System.out.println.

Instead, first save it into a String:

```
String token = st.nextToken();
```

then you can use the same String in your print and for the array.

Answer (score 0):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa989865(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa989865%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> StringTokenizer.nextToken () : Gets the next token in the string
>   during parsing.

```
numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
System.out.println(row + " " + col + " = " + st.nextToken());
```

You go through your tokens without using them !